# Transcoder and Transcribe SDKs. Do I also Need SQS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder, amazon-transcribe

I am developing a Spring Boot application where I need to upload an mp3 file into Amazon S3 Bucket, then cut it within a specific time frame using [Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) and finally have that audio part converted into text using [Transcribe](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/).

I had a look at the java samples mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/sample-code.html#java-sample) and noticed that Transcoder API also makes use of [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/). Furthermore the sample seems overly complex using a lot of threads and synchronized blocks for SQS.

My Question is Do I really need to utilize SQS to achieve the concept I described above?

Answer (score 1):

No, in the samples SQS is used for sending **notifications** only , if you don't want notifications , you actually don't need SQS in your use case, the transcribe service is enough to do your work

Comment: Thanks. But how can I know when transcoding job is finished so I can then proceed to transcribe?

Comment: If you are not using SNS service for notifications , you can list your jobs based on their status, like list jobs which have **completed** status. You can refer more here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/list-jobs-by-status.html#list-jobs-by-status-examples